# Centering a table in HTML5

Tags: html

How can I center a table in HTML5? (or with css if needed)

I tried using `<center\>` but most browsers dropped support for HTML4 (for the most part)

For context, I am building a simple homepage to link to my socials - This HTML file will be used with a Flask server

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>CodeSoft</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/api/files/style">
  <meta name="description" content="I do coding stuff,">

  <meta property="og:title" content="CodeSoft">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">

  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any">
  <link rel="icon" href="/icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/icon.png">

  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#fafafa">
</head>
<body>

  <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
  <h2>Hi,</h2>
  <h1>I'm CodeSoft</h1>
  <div class="socials">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="https://github.com/CodeSoftGit" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="/static/github-logo.svg" alt="GitHub" width="20" height="20"/>
          </a>
        </td>
        <td>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7PN0wxaTXkT01YTAo1zZNQ" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
            <img src="/static/youtube-logo.svg" alt="YouTube" width="20" height="20"/>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@300&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
  }

h2 {
    font-size: 22px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
}
.socials {
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: On your table add **width** so it will center it's content ```<table width="100%">```.

Comment: In the CSS add: `table { width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.socials {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
```